# Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect (React app in Laravel Framework)

Tags: reactjs, laravel, redux

I have a react app inside laravel api and Im having this error. I cant seem to find a way to remove this from console, I also don't know if this error relates to the forms not displaying initialValues on connect.

[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1dPD.png)

here's my index.js

```
# index.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import App from "./components/App";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
  <App />
  </Provider,
   document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and the App.js that has the ApplicationScreen connect

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ submissionSuccess, ...props }) =>
  submissionSuccess ? <Route {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/applications" />;

const CSPPrivateRoute = ({ submissionSuccess, ...props }) =>
  submissionSuccess ? <Route {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/applications" />;

const ApplicationScreens = ({
  match,
  submissionSuccess,
  cspSubmissionSuccess
}) => (
  <Container>
    <Switch>
      <Route path={`${match.url}/license_to_operate`} component={LTOScreen} />
      <Route path={`${match.url}/csp`} component={CSPScreen} />
      <PrivateRoute
        submissionSuccess={submissionSuccess}
        path={`${match.url}/submission_complete`}
        component={SubmissionCompleteScreen}
      />
      <CSPPrivateRoute
        submissionSuccess={cspSubmissionSuccess}
        path={`${match.url}/csp_submission_complete`}
        component={CSPSubmissionCompleteScreen}
      />
      <Route path={`${match.url}/*`}>
        <Redirect to="/404" />
      </Route>
      <Route
        path={match.url}
        component={() => (
          <Fragment>
            <h2 className="my-3">Applications</h2>
            <hr />
            <CardDeckSelections data={APPLICATIONS_SELECTIONS} />
          </Fragment>
        )}
      />
    </Switch>
  </Container>
);

const mapStateToProps = ({ submissionComplete, cspSubmissionComplete }) => {
  const { submissionSuccess } = submissionComplete;
  const { cspSubmissionSuccess } = cspSubmissionComplete;
  return { submissionSuccess, cspSubmissionSuccess };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ApplicationScreens);
```

What am I missing something here?
if the information above is not enough I'd be more than willing and happy to add more.

Comment: Should be `<Provider store={store}>` see [documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider#props)

Comment: tried that but no luck.